# KeyBindings stuck on actionPerformed()

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

If you add a Key Binding in java with a mask - let's just say the ActionEvent.ALT_MASK with KeyEvent.VK_A - and then you perform that key (ALT + A) BUT, you release the alt key *just* before the 'A' key, you will usually encounter a problem where the actionPerformed() in a class (implementing ActionListener) will keep being activated. This probably (98% sure) means that the Key Binding never registered that the key was released. If you release the 'A' key before the alt key, you are fine, but - like I said - if you release the alt key perhaps 1/10 of a second before the other key, it keeps repeating.

Note: This only happens - apparently - in my program ([here](http://pastebin.com/LxXXshXu))

Try it for yourself if you don't believe me. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    public ConwayPanel() {
        super();

        setBackground(new Color(245, 255, 245, 255)); // BG slightly green - all ready

        paused = true; // nothing to play... in FUTURE put cool organism in

        startX = 0; // starting position of the left of the grid
        startY = 0; // starting position of the top of the grid
        zoom = 15; // the width of each cell (EXCLUDING the lines that make up the boundaries)
        cellNum = 1000; // The number of cells

        cells = new boolean[cellNum][cellNum]; // populate cells with false/dead

        currentX = 0; // current x cursor position
        currentY = 0; // current y cursor position

        flipBoundaries = new int[4];

        hideCurrentPos = false; // don't want to hide cursor position unless explicitly told to do so

        defineMaps(); // creates Key enums
        setKeyBindings(); // defines Key and KeyNoMask key bindings
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new KeyListener());
        timer.start();

        setupMouseListeners(); // creates MouseListener, MouseMotionListener and MouseWheelListener

        setFocusable(true); // make isFocusable() true
        requestFocusInWindow(); // get focus for listeners
    }

    private void defineMaps() {
        for (KeyAltMask key : KeyAltMask.values()) {
            keyMap.put(key, false); // value true when key is pressed - all initiated to false
        }
        for (KeyNoMask key : KeyNoMask.values()) {
            keyNoMaskMap.put(key, false); // value true when key is pressed - all initiated to false
        }
    }

    private void setKeyBindings() {
        InputMap inMap = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED/* or... WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW*/);
        ActionMap actMap = getActionMap();

        for (final KeyAltMask key : KeyAltMask.values()) {
            KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(), ActionEvent.ALT_MASK, false); // just right! (not blocking shortcut key and preventing accidental keyboard mishaps)
            KeyStroke released = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(), ActionEvent.ALT_MASK, true); // just right! (not blocking shortcut key and preventing accidental keyboard mishaps)

            inMap.put(pressed, key.toString() + "pressed");
            inMap.put(released, key.toString() + "released");

            actMap.put(key.toString() + "pressed", new AbstractAction() { // adds each value of Key into a HashMap (when the key is pressed) and puts that HashMap action into ActionMap

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyMap.put(key, true);
                }
            });

            actMap.put(key.toString() + "released", new AbstractAction() { // adds each value of Key into a HashMap (when the key is released) and puts that HashMap action into ActionMap

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyMap.put(key, false);
                }
            });
        }

        for (final KeyNoMask key : KeyNoMask.values()) {
            KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(), 0, false);
            KeyStroke released = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(), 0, true);
            inMap.put(pressed, key.toString() + "pressed");
            inMap.put(released, key.toString() + "released");
            actMap.put(key.toString() + "pressed", new AbstractAction() { // adds each value of KeyNoMask into a HashMap (when the key is pressed) and puts that HashMap action into ActionMap

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyNoMaskMap.put(key, true);
                }
            });
            actMap.put(key.toString() + "released", new AbstractAction() { // adds each value of KeyNoMask into a HashMap (when the key is released) and puts that HashMap action into ActionMap

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyNoMaskMap.put(key, false);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class KeyListener implements ActionListener { // probably not great to have same name, but "real" KeyListener not imported

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (KeyAltMask key : KeyAltMask.values()) { // run through the ALL of the keys
                if (keyMap.get(key)) { // if key in HashMap is true (i.e. the actionPerformed() above set it true)
                    switch(key.toString()) {
                        case "c": // clear all cells and pause if not paused
                            for (int y = 0; y < cellNum; y++) {
                                for (int x = 0; x < cellNum; x++) {
                                    cells[x][y] = false;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!paused) {
                                paused = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "f": // fill all cells and pause if not paused
                            for (int y = 0; y < cellNum; y++) {
                                for (int x = 0; x < cellNum; x++) {
                                    cells[x][y] = true;
                                }
                                if (!paused) {
                                    paused = true;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case "i": // invert all cells and pause if not paused
                            for (int y = 0; y < cellNum; y++) {
                                for (int x = 0; x < cellNum; x++) {
                                    cells[x][y] = !cells[x][y];
                                }
                                if (!paused) {
                                    paused = true;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case "l": // lock all cells that have a live/true cell
                            for (int y = 0; y < cellNum; y++) {
                                for (int x = 0; x < cellNum; x++) {
                                    if (cells[x][y]) {
                                        //set Lock
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case "p": // pause/play
                            paused = !paused;
                            break;
                        case "s": // step once
                            step = true;
                            break;
                        case "h": // hide current cursor position
                            hideCurrentPos = !hideCurrentPos;
                            break;
//                        default:
                    }
                }
            }

            for (KeyNoMask key : KeyNoMask.values()) { //  run through ALL of the keys (this is the beauty of key bindings - you can move the cursor diagonally). I kinda like a pause after the first key press, though
                if (keyNoMaskMap.get(key)) { // if key in HashMap is true (i.e. the actionPerformed() above returned true)
                    switch(key.toString()) { // move cursor position appropriately and pause if not paused
                        case "down":
                            currentY += currentY == cellNum - 1 ? 0 : 1;
                            if (!paused) {
                                paused = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "up":
                            currentY -= currentY == 0 ? 0 : 1;
                            if (!paused) {
                                paused = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "left":
                            currentX -= currentX == 0 ? 0 : 1;
                            if (!paused) {
                                paused = true;
                            }

                            break;
                        case "right":
                            currentX += currentX == cellNum - 1 ? 0 : 1;
                            if (!paused) {
                                paused = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "space": // flip pixel at current cursor position
                            flipCell(currentX, currentY);
                            if (!paused) {
                                paused = true;
                            }
//                        default:
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's a lot of code, but it's pretty standard for KeyBindings at least. So, I was wondering if there was a way to get around this. Is this the os's fault or is it Java's fault and  how can I fix it. I would like to avoid having an `else` in `actionPerformed()` because I need this to be fast. Also, is there anyway to optimize the `actionPerformed()` method because it seems like it might be a little bit screwy.

I just put this together, but **it doesn't do it here**! Small executable:

```
package bindingstest;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Dylan AND Hovercraft Full Of Eels
 */
public class BindingsTest {
    static Map<Key, Boolean> keyMap = new HashMap<>();

    enum Key { // possibly used in conjunction with mask in order to prevent keyboard mishaps - it will probably be ALT in FUTURE
        a(KeyEvent.VK_A),
        b(KeyEvent.VK_B),
        c(KeyEvent.VK_C),
        d(KeyEvent.VK_D),
        e(KeyEvent.VK_E),
        f(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        private final int keyCode;

        private Key(int keyCode) {
            this.keyCode = keyCode; // KeyEvent.VK_...
        }

        public int getKeyCode() {
            return keyCode;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(50, 50, 1000, 1000);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();

        for (Key key : Key.values()) {
            keyMap.put(key, false);
        }

        InputMap inMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actMap = panel.getActionMap();

        for (final Key key : Key.values()) {
            KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(), ActionEvent.ALT_MASK, false);
            KeyStroke released = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(), ActionEvent.ALT_MASK, true);

            inMap.put(pressed, key.toString() + "pressed");
            inMap.put(released, key.toString() + "released");

            actMap.put(key.toString() + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyMap.put(key, true);
                }
            });

            actMap.put(key.toString() + "released", new AbstractAction() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyMap.put(key, false);
                }
            });
        }

        for (final Key key : Key.values()) {
            KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(), 0, false);
            KeyStroke released = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(), 0, true);
            inMap.put(pressed, key.toString() + "pressed");
            inMap.put(released, key.toString() + "released");
            actMap.put(key.toString() + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyMap.put(key, true);
                }
            });
            actMap.put(key.toString() + "released", new AbstractAction() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyMap.put(key, false);
                }
            });
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new KeyListener());
        timer.start();

        frame.add(panel);
    }

    private static class KeyListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (Key key : Key.values()) { // run through the ALL of the keys
                if (keyMap.get(key)) { // if key in HashMap is true (i.e. the actionPerformed() above set it true)
                    switch(key.toString()) {
                        case "a":
                            System.out.println("a");
                            break;
                        case "b":
                            System.out.println("b");
                            break;
                        case "c":
                            System.out.println("c");
                            break;
                        case "d":
                            System.out.println("d");
                            break;
                        case "e":
                            System.out.println("e");
                            break;
                        case "f":
                            System.out.println("f");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Try it for yourself if you don't believe me."` -- I'd love to, but in order to do that, you should first create and post your small runnable/compilable [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because your snippet won't compile nor run for me. `"It's a lot of code,..."` -- and that's the beauty of the minimal example program, -- it **isn't** a lot of code, making it much easier for us to get to the meat of the issue.

Comment: Note, some of that code looks suspiciously like *my* code.

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with this. ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hm, I learned this a couple months ago and I can't remember where I got it, but that's how I implement it. I believe I found this on code ranch a while back. If it is your code, then I don't know what to tell you. I'll add you into authorship. Although, you did put it up online without copyright.

Comment: Also, there's compilable code now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I see what you're saying, and thanks for posting compilable code. One solution to use both release KeyStrokes, one for alt-key and one for plain key.  For example,

```
  InputMap inMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
  ActionMap actMap = panel.getActionMap();

  for (final Key key : Key.values()) {
     KeyStroke altPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(),
           InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK, false);
     KeyStroke altReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(),
           InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK, true);
     KeyStroke released  = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.getKeyCode(),
           0, true);

     inMap.put(altPressed, altPressed.toString());
     inMap.put(altReleased, altReleased.toString());
     inMap.put(released, released.toString());

     actMap.put(altPressed.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           keyMap.put(key, true);
        }
     });

     Action releaseAction = new AbstractAction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           keyMap.put(key, false);
        }
     };

     actMap.put(altReleased.toString(), releaseAction);
     actMap.put(released.toString(), releaseAction);
```

---

Another solution is to not do the above, but rather to re-set the Map with each iteration of the Timer:

```
     for (Key key : Key.values()) { // run through the ALL of the keys
        if (keyMap.get(key)) { // if key in HashMap is true (i.e. the
                               // actionPerformed() above set it true)
           switch (key.toString()) {
           case "a":
              System.out.println("a");
              break;
           case "b":
              System.out.println("b");
              break;
           case "c":
              System.out.println("c");
              break;
           case "d":
              System.out.println("d");
              break;
           case "e":
              System.out.println("e");
              break;
           case "f":
              System.out.println("f");
           }

           // ***** add this *****
           keyMap.put(key, Boolean.FALSE);
        }
     }
```

This second solution suffers from the delay that the OS puts in keystroke submission when the key is held down.

Comment: Thanks. This half fixes another problem (when I press a key once, it often repeats at least twice), **however** I'm afraid it doesn't solve the issue and creates another problem: The repeat still occurs, and - in addition - now I cannot move two ways with arrow keys and use another key (without mask). Here is ALL of my code (sorry, I didn't add you as author here because I already pasted it to pastebin): [http://pastebin.com/LxXXshXu](http://pastebin.com/LxXXshXu). If you want to, you can just paste this into Netbeans/Eclipse/text editor and run it and try to make the key binding repeat.

Comment: I have *two* classes, one with a main (called Conways.java) and the other that extends JPanel (sorry I think I said JFrame) which is called ConwayPanel.java.